# Aurelia loading of html ressources change viewmodel value

Tags: aurelia

i have a strange issue with binding.
i have a select where the items came from server side, which i load by a promise and stored in the view model as  `private allStudios: Studio[];`

the select binds to `@bindable currentStudioId: number = 0;`

in activate method of my viewmodel i set `currentStudioId` for instance to value 8. since this moment the value of `currentStudioId` is 8 (i trace this with log outputs).

but after the following line in log

`DEBUG [templating] importing resources for routes/member/user-workouts/edit-user-workout.html []`

suddently the value of `currentStudioId` get set to the value of the first item in `allStudios: Studio[];`
so my question is, why does the loading of the html ressources changes the value of my viedmodel property? can anyone help me?

edit (how i bind to viewmodel property):

```
<select class="form-control" value.bind="curSelectedStudioId">
<option repeat.for="s of allStudios" model.bind="s.id">${s.name}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Show us how you've bound the value in the HTML? Blocks of code, that give context, are so much more useful that random snippets.

Comment: You should be using `value` instead of `bind`. `<option repeat.for="s of allStudios" value.bind="s.id">${s.name}</option>`. Bind is for objects. Also, any reasons for using `@bindable` ?

Comment: value would be two-way binding? yes, the reason for bindable is that if this value changes i need to fire some additional methods which i call at `curSelectedStudioIdChanged`

Comment: ah i see! sorry for my quesition about two-way binding in prev. comment! has there been any changes in aurelia? because two month ago this code worked fine?

Comment: You should use `observable`, not `bindable` for this use case.